# WSO2 governance registry and enterprise service bus (ESB) can be integrated?

Tags: wso2, soa, esb, wso2-esb

We use WSO2 tools for our SOA. We are examining the possibility of use of Registry Governance to manage the services available. I wonder if someone has already done the integration of Registry Governance and ESB, so that services are built on only one tool to another and replicated.