# WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus and WSO2 Governance Registry Integration

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am Trying to integrate wso2 Governance registry server and ESB server. I have used These links for help: http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/deployment_guide.html  http://charithaka.blogspot.in/2011/11/wso2-deployment-synchronizer-sharing.html.

My mysql is from another pc on same network. I have changed my registry.xml as described in above urls for Governance registry, but when i run the wso2server.bat file of governance registry, i get error like this:-

```
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:04,537]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon... {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:04,567]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Windows 7 6.1, x86 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:04,568]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : D:\eclipse\java\jdk1.7.0\jre {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:04,568]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.7.0 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:04,568]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 21.0-b17,Oracle Corporation {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:04,568]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : D:\eclipse\WSO2\WSO2GR~1.1\bin\.. {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:04,568]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : D:\eclipse\WSO2\WSO2GR~1.1\bin\..\tmp {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:04,569]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : 313123, en-US, Asia/Calcutta {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}

TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:04,760]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  RAM size (MB): 2047 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2048 {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter}

TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:05,022]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS}
```

Error

```
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:09,355] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil} -  Database Error - Table 'reg_db.um_dialect' doesn't exist {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil}
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'reg_db.um_dialect' doesn't exist
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3176)1:08 PM 2/15/20131:23 PM 2/15/2013
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1266)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:163)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:279)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:109)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:233)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:128)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:67)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

   TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:09,372] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService} -  Cannot initialize the realm. {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService}
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database Error - Table 'reg_db.um_dialect' doesn't exist
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:169)
at    org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:279)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:109)
at     org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:233)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:128)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:67)
at       org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'reg_db.um_dialect' doesn't exist
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3176)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1266)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:163)
... 22 more

TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-02-15 12:50:09,387] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator}
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:237)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:128)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:67)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database Error - Table 'reg_db.um_dialect' doesn't exist
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:169)
at     org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:279)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:109)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:233)
... 19 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'reg_db.um_dialect' doesn't exist
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3176)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1266)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:163)
... 22 more
```

Plz help me. I really need your help as i am a beginner.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: <currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig> <readOnly>false</readOnly> <registryRoot>/</registryRoot> <dbConfig name="wso2registry"> <url>jdbc:mysql://10.224.188.94:3306/reg_db?autoReconnect=true</url> <userName>root</userName> <password>root</password> <driverName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverName> <maxActive>50</maxActive> <maxWait>60000</maxWait> <minIdle>5</minIdle> </dbConfig> This i have put on registry.xml

Comment: and  <Property name="url">jdbc:mysql://10.224.188.94:3306/reg_db?autoReconnect=true</Property> <Property name="userName">root</Property> <Property name="password">root</Property> <Property name="driverName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Property> <Property name="maxActive">50</Property> <Property name="maxWait">60000</Property> <Property name="minIdle">5</Property>  on user-mgt.xml inside configuration tag

Comment: please read FAQ on how to format a question - it's *a mess* in the current form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you try starting the Governance Registry with the following command.

```
wso2server.bat -Dsetup
```

This will create the required tables for the first time. (So need to do only once)

Comment: What will happen if I do it second time? It will drop all the tables and recreate them again?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting mysql exception because the table reg_db.um_dialect does not exist

you can check that in stack trace check you are connected to correct db having reg_db.um_dialect table

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'reg_db.um_dialect' doesn't exist
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
```

Comment: How to check that both my esb and governace registry has been integrated?

Comment: Check this link similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619425/wso2-governance-registry-and-enterprise-service-bus-esb-can-be-integrated?rq=1